# How to access preexcute data in doinbackground?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I fetch a database and display value in a spinner in preexcute value.in doinbackground thread i want to insert that spinner value in a sqlite table,I know that i can not use ui component in doinbackground. Expecting your help.
Here are my preexcute value

```
try {
            statement = connect.prepareStatement("exec dbo.getSalesIdtest;");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e("Error 1 here: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Log.e("error 2 here: ", ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            while(rs.next()) {
                TextView generateData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getOrderid);
                pab = rs.getString("CurrentNo");
                generateData.setText(pab);
                Log.e(pab,"Message here is");
              boolean isInserted = orderDB.insertorderData(rs.getString("CurrentNo"));

                if (isInserted == true)
                    Toast.makeText(orderChalan.this, "Data save successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(orderChalan.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and here is code in my doinbackground

```
if (con == null) {
                                z = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                            } else {
                                String query = "insert into dbo.slsOrderD(osdSalesID,osdProductID,osdQty)values('joy','" + getRata.getString(1).toString() + "','" + getRata.getString(2).toString() + "');";
                                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                                z = "New client's data added successfully";
                                isSuccess = true;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            isSuccess = false;
                            z = "Exceptions";
                            Log.e("ERRO", ex.getMessage());
                        }
```

In insert statement i have to access data from pre execute spinner element how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare variables that you are updating in your *onPreExecute()* as **class members** of your inherited version of Asynctask, then you should be able to access them from the *doInBackground()*.

From what I see you are declaring them as local variables in *OnPreExecute()*